# Дизайн интернет-страниц

Tags: веб-дизайн, вёрстка

Не могу вспомнить, как называется тип верстки интернет-сайта, когда вся информация выдается на одной странице. Получается что-то типа очень длинного портка, в начале которого идет форма, например, заказа (подписки/регистрации), потом подробная динамическая инфа о специфике продукта и в самом конце снова форма заказа (подписки/регистрации). Не сайт-визитка, а есть какое-то специальное название.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Landing page.